# How to get the line of text clicked in a textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a text view with multiple lines of text e.g.

This is line 1

This is line 2

This is line 3

I want to be able to store the text depending on which line the user has clicked, i.e. if they click on line 2 I want to store "This is line 2".

How can I go about this?

**Edited 1 Sept:**

I am not sure how the clickable span solution would work? I am able to get a specific line of text from my text view e.g. to get line 1 I would use:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.class_list);
String selectedClass =(String)(tv).getText();
int l1start = tv.getLayout().getLineStart(1);
int l1end = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(1);
String l1 = selectedClass.substring(l1start, l1end);
```

But I can't see how to work out which line number has actually been clicked by using clickable span?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575376/line-numbers-code-highlighting-in-textview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [clickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) span . Set a different span for each line and When clicked onClick method for this clickable span will be called.